# Route 53 resolving to Elastic Beanstalk subdomain not custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a site hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.  I have a domain registered with Hover.  I have added the AWS name servers to the hover account.  I have created a Alias record in Route53.

When I go to the domain my I get routed to the site but the EB subdomain is shown in the browser.  How do I get the domain to show?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a DNS/Route53 configuration issue. This is a configuration issue with the software you have running on your Elastic Beanstalk instance(s). Your web server software is issuing the redirect because it isn't aware of the custom domain you have configured. What software are you running on EB exactly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It was a setting in wordpress that redirected it.